# Dynamic Include statements for eager loading in a query - EF 4.3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-4.3

I have this method:

```
public CampaignCreative GetCampaignCreativeById(int id)
        {
            using (var db = GetContext())
            {
                return db.CampaignCreatives
                    .Include("Placement")
                    .Include("CreativeType")                    
                    .Include("Campaign")
                    .Include("Campaign.Handshake")
                    .Include("Campaign.Handshake.Agency")
                    .Include("Campaign.Product")
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

I would like to make the list of Includes dynamic. I tried:

```
public CampaignCreative GetCampaignCreativeById(int id, string[] includes)
        {
            using (var db = GetContext())
            {
                var query = db.CampaignCreatives;

                foreach (string include in includes)
                {
                    query = query.Include(include);
                }

                return query.AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();                    
            }
        }
```

But it didn't compile. I got this error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Does anyone know how to make the list of Includes dynamic?

Thanks

Comment: I did a plugin that do just that here is the link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1205294/Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Include-Hierarchy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make the `query` variable queryable:

```
public CampaignCreative GetCampaignCreativeById(int id, string[] includes)
{
    using (var db = GetContext())
    {
        var query = db.CampaignCreatives.AsQueryable();
        foreach (string include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        return query
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id))
            .FirstOrDefault();                    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.  IQueryable has no Include method.  This doesn't compile.

Comment: Some projects you will get a compile error with this solution. Add using System.Data.Entity; to access the Include extension method on IQueryable

Comment: This does not work For EF4.0. Missing Include extension

Comment: IQuerable does not have Include extension for EF4.0. For EF4.0 you oppositely cast IQuerable<T> to ObjectQuery<T>. Then you can include details.

Comment: does someone have code snipped for nested includes?

Answer (score 40):

I am more fond of the non-string expressive way of defining includes. Mainly because it doesn't rely on magic strings.

For the example code, it would look something like this:

```
public CampaignCreative GetCampaignCreativeById(int id) {
    using (var db = GetContext()) {
        return db.CampaignCreatives
            .Include(cc => cc.Placement)
            .Include(cc => cc.CreativeType)                    
            .Include(cc => cc.Campaign.Select(c => 
                 c.Handshake.Select(h => h.Agency)))
            .Include(cc => cc.Campaign.Select(c => c.Product)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And to make those dynamic, this is how you do that:

```
public CampaignCreative GetCampaignCreativeById(
    int id, 
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes
) {
    using (var db = GetContext()) {
        var query = db.CampaignCreatives;
        return includes
            .Aggregate(
                query.AsQueryable(), 
                (current, include) => current.Include(include)
            )
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
var c = dataService.GetCampaignCreativeById(
     1, 
     cc => cc.Placement, 
     cc => cc.CreativeType, 
     cc => cc.Campaign.Select(c => c.Handshake.Select(h => h.Agency)),
     cc => cc.Campaign.Select(c => c.Product
);
```

Comment: I said it above but I'll say it here in case anyone missed it: Some projects you will get a compile error with this solution. Add using System.Data.Entity; to access the Include extension method on IQueryable.

Comment: This answer should've been the one checked up. I found it extremely useful when it comes to EF strongly typed navigation properties on generic types.

Comment: But when you see transformed SQL for this LINQ, the above includes always shows inner joins. Is there a way you could achive left or right joins using the same method of includes. For reference I'm including my post link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129505/how-to-implement-left-join-on-lambda-linq-expression-with-includes Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Giving the compiler a hint by using `IQueryable<CampaignCreative>` instead of `var` will work too.

```
IQueryable<CampaignCreative> query = db.CampaignCreatives;
// or
DbQuery<CampaignCreative> query = db.CampaignCreatives;
```

When using `var` the compiler infers `DbSet<T>` for `query` which is more specific than the type returned by `Include` (which is `DbQuery<T>` (=base class of `DbSet<T>`) implementing `IQueryable<T>`), so you can't assign the result to the `query` variable anymore. Hence the compiler error on the `query = query.Include(include)` line.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this method to retrieve any set of entity dynamically based on their types. I used the `IDbEntity` interface to provide a valid key to search the userId in all the classes.
The `Util.GetInverseProperties<T>()` method is used to get the properties needed in the `Include` statement.

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(string userId) where T : class, IDbEntity
{
    var query = db.Set<T>().Where(l => l.UserId==userId);

    var props = Util.GetInverseProperties<T>();
    foreach (var include in props)
        query = query.Include(include.Name);

    return query
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

```cs
public interface IDbEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public static List<PropertyInfo> GetInverseProperties<T>()
{
    return typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(InversePropertyAttribute)))
        .ToList();
}
```