# How to eagerly load all referenced entities dynamically in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

- EF 6
- I have the following POCO's

_

```
public class StructureEntity : EmEntityBase
{
    [ForeignKey("ParentStructureId")]
    public virtual StructureEntity ParentStructure { get; set; }

    public long? ParentStructureId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
    public virtual SiteEntity Site { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public long SiteId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SiteEntity : EmEntityBase
{
    [ForeignKey("ParentSiteId")]
    public virtual SiteEntity ParentSite { get; set; }

    public long? ParentSiteId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public ClientEntity Client { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientEntity : EmEntityBase
{
    public long? ParentClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentClientId")]
    public virtual ClientEntity ParentClient { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I want to eagerly load all the referenced entities. To do this I have:

```
    public IQueryable<StructureDivisionEntity> GetAllWithInclude()
   {
   return GetAll()
         .Include(e => e.Structure)
         .Include(e => e.ParentStructureDivision.Structure)
         .Include(e => e.Structure.Site.Client);
   }
```

I was wondering if there was a dynamic way to do this without explicitly having to do the .Include(Structure) etc. Something along the lines of:

MyEntity.IncludeAllReferenced() where IncludeAllReferenced used reflection or similair to traverse MyEntity and do all the includes?

**UPDATE: Alternative Approach To Querying Complex Graphs**

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247254/Improving-Entity-Framework-Query-Performance-Using
- https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1386
- https://github.com/oinuar/GBQ

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512285/entity-framework-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-eager-load-child-entities-wit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656157/generic-find-with-includes-entity-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001061/dynamic-include-statements-for-eager-loading-in-a-query-ef-4-3-1

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but you can make an extensionmethod to get all.
This might be a crazy idea, but you could make a generic extension-method to handle all your types, to make the code more clean.

Example, (one could extend this with factory-pattern if necessary):

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(StructureDivisionEntity))
   {
       return GetAllWithInclude(query);
   }
   throw new NotImplementedException("IncludeAll not implemented for type {0}",typeof(T).FullName);
}

private static IQueryable<StructureDivisionEntity> GetAllWithInclude<StructureDivisionEntity> (IQueryable<StructureDivisionEntity> query) 
{
   return query.Include(e => e.Structure)
               .Include(e => e.ParentStructureDivision.Structure)
               .Include(e => e.Structure.Site.Client);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Pity I still have to "hard code" the Include() calls I want to do.