# Entity Framework 6 Generic Eager Loading Query Method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading, npgsql

I am writing a generic querying method in Entity Framework 6, based off of this helpful [article](http://www.itworld.com/article/2700950/development/a-generic-repository-for--net-entity-framework-6-with-async-operations.html). Here's how it looks:

```
    public static T QueryEagerLoad<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match) where T : class
    {
        using (var databaseContext = new ClearspanDatabaseContext())
        {
            databaseContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            T retrievedObject = databaseContext.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(match);
            return retrievedObject;
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to eagerly load any related entities, so I include disable to configuration variable `LazyLoadingEnabled`. While it loads the object, it does not load the related entities, per my view in the debugger. Why would this be? Am I missing something? I should note that I'm using Npgsql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to disable lazy loading does not mean to enable eager loading 'per default', it only disables the loading of related entities lazily. for eager loading you'll still have to include the navigation property... refer to the comments at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOffProperty on this topic. as far as I know, there is no way to determine navigation properties at run time, you'll have to provide them in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your comment, I was led to the conclusion represented in the answer I've posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Mikael Östberg's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001061/dynamic-include-statements-for-eager-loading-in-a-query-ef-4-3-1). To use a generic method for querying with eager loading, it seems necessary to inject the includes. Here's how the generic method shaped up:

```
public static T Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes) where T : class
{
    using (var databaseContext = new ClearspanDatabaseContext())
    {
        var dataSet = databaseContext.Set<T>(); // Get the relevant DataSet
        T retrievedObject = includes.Aggregate( // Eagerly load the passed navigation properties
                dataSet.AsQueryable(),
                (current, include) => current.Include(include)
            ).SingleOrDefault(match); // Find exactly one or zero matches
        return retrievedObject;
    }
}
```

And an example of a call that injects the properties to eagerly load (the `includes` parameter in the generic method above):

```
public static Lumber GetLumber(int databaseId)
{
    Expression<Func<Lumber, object>> lengthProperty = (lumber => lumber.Length);
    Expression<Func<Lumber, object>> thicknessProperty = (lumber => lumber.Thickness);
    Expression<Func<Lumber, object>> widthProperty = (lumber => lumber.Width);

    List<Expression<Func<Lumber, object>>> lumberNaviationProperties = new List<Expression<Func<Lumber, object>>>() { lengthProperty, thicknessProperty, widthProperty };

    Lumber retrievedLumber = DatabaseOperations.Query<Lumber>((lumber => lumber.DatabaseId == databaseId), lumberNaviationProperties);

    return retrievedLumber;
}
```