# How to add list of include in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using specification pattern and I have written a method for adding include to a list. Type of items in this list is `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` where `TEntity` is my base entity class.

Is there any way to iterate them and add include to an `IQueryable` field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Include statements for eager loading in a query - EF 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001061/dynamic-include-statements-for-eager-loading-in-a-query-ef-4-3-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate one your list of includes and add them to your IQueryable variable. Here is a way to do it using LINQ aggreagte method:

```
 query = includes.Aggreagte(queryable, (current, next) => 
                            current.Include(next));
```